# How can I fix not being able to find Express

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I have NodeJs installed, v10.15.3.
I have run `npm install -g nodemon" and "npm install -g express`.
In my `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\` folder.

I see express and express.cmd, and in the node_modules folder I see the express subfolder.

The `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\` folder is on my path. 
However, when I start my server up with nodemon, I get an error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
```

Any ideas of what I've done wrong?

Comment: Express needs to be installed locally in your project and not globally on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to `require()` a module in your Nodejs package, the module needs to exist in your package's package cache (in the `./node_modules` directory within your package's source directory).

In order to add a package to your program's package cache, first make sure you have a `package.json` file, then use `npm` to install the dependency.  In other words, run:

```
npm init
```

...and answer the questions, then run:

```
npm install --save express
```

After these steps, you should be able to run your Nodejs program.